# Does a moving object with a constant velocity do any work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, velocity

Since Work=Force$\cdot$ Distance and the net force on a moving body is zero, does that mean that no work is done by a body moving with a constant speed?
Also, the work done is the energy expended. If a moving body does not do any work, does that mean it expends zero energy? If that's the case, why is the formula for the kinetic energy of a moving body (KE$= (1/2)mv^2$) applicable?

Answer (score 4):

There is not enough information to answer the question. Initially one would say "no":

$$ \frac {dW}{dt} = \vec F \cdot \vec v $$

and a body moving at constant $\vec v$ has $\vec F=0$....Newton's law.

But what if that body is a rocket moving upward at constant velocity? Then it is doing work against the gravitational force, or it's a ship in the ocean pushing water around?

Answer (score 2):

Per the work energy theorem the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Therefore the *net work* on an object moving at constant velocity is zero.

But that doesn’t mean there is no work being done on the object. Examples are pushing an object at constant velocity on a surface with friction and lifting an object at constant velocity.

In the first example the person pushing the object does positive work on the object and the kinetic friction force does an equal amount of negative work on the object. In the second example the person lifting the object does positive work on the object and the force of gravity does an equal amount of negative work on the object.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Work is done as a result of a change in energy. Although an object moving with constant speed has constant kinetic energy, it may still do work as a result of changes in other forms of energy. For example, a weight falling at a constant speed can do work because of the change in its potential energy (this is the principle of the [longcase clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_clock)) or an object that is completely stationary and so has zero kinetic energy can do work because of a change in its chemical energy (e.g. a fire).

Comment: " a weight falling at a constant speed " - with gravity, it's acceleration.  No accelaration no work. However, energy seems to be transferable without acceleration involved.

Comment: @PeterBernhard "No acceleration no work" - not true. There is no mention of acceleration in work = force times distance. Change in kinetic energy is one possible source of work, but there are many others that involve no acceleration whatsoever.

Comment: I find my long-lived mistake in your statement. I insist - yes, there is, "metion of acceleration in work = force times distance" - the acceleration is within the force. Be the force with you :-)

Comment: @PeterBernhard Suppose you push a block up an inclined plane at constant speed. You are doing work against gravity, which results in an increase in the potential energy of the block, even though its kinetic energy remains constant. Yet your claim seems to be that since the block is not accelerating then no work is done on it ??

Comment: First guess: the block you shovel up has done work against gravity, there has been acceleration. Actually, "to wave off"..., that issue "potential" energy seems to be set apart from the issue that f, force, has time and acceleration "in it". The formula W = f times s doesn't show. Likewise, "potential" energy as a concept doesn't show off the work that has been done accelerating against gravity. Holding on.

Answer (score 0):

From the work-energy theorem you know that $L_{\rm total}= \Delta K$.  If you have $\vec{F}_{total}=\vec{0}$ so trivially $L_{\rm total}=0$ and by the theorem $\Delta K=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Work done is at the expense or transferrence of energy and kinetic energy is best way to transfer energy. If a particle has kinetic energy or moving with constant speed, it can impart its energy to whatever stops or slows it down. Force is acted against moving body, so moving body lose energy and system or body that slows it down gain energy.

Second thing, it is not that particle with constant speed is not acted upon by force. It is true for projectiles, but they slowed down after a while. For other bodies moving with constant speed, then they are acted upon by force or energy source, a car moving with constant speed is driven by combustion of fuel or thrust by piston.